# Heat basement from excess heat in boiler room

Tags: hvac, ducts, heat

I'm trying to heat a basement room using excess heat from the boiler room but it isn't working.  I've run two 4 inch flex ducts from the boiler room to the main 300 square foot room at opposite ends.  I've then added booster fans.  These ducts are outputting 75 degree air but the room never gets above 61 degrees.  Without the fans on the room is about 59 degrees.

The one booster fan is rated at 200cfm, the other is 100cfm.

I can't run larger ducts.

If I run a 6 inch fan through the 4 inch duct would that pump more air?

I've experimented with using one duct as a return but that didn't help.

Any advice would be appriciated.

Comment: 4 inch ducts of any significant length are, to put it mildly, ***pathetic.*** Worse if they are flex duct, so if you can't increase size, use rigid duct and add more of them.

Comment: It the basement room insulated? Well? Is there a staircase allowing the heat to rise? What's the air temp in the room you're pumping it from?

Comment: Are you using a push pull one duct supply’s the basement room 1 returns the air back to the boiler room. Without a complete path once the basement pressurizes or pulls a vacuum on the boiler the flow will stop and may cause other issues if your boiler is open combustion. In that case out flow must be balanced if allowed in your jurisdiction at all.

Comment: How hot is the boiler room if you don't remove the excess heat?

Comment: Sadly the tiles are very high so 4 inch flex duct might be my only option.  The basement room is insulated.

Comment: There is a staircase, but there is a door at the top.  The boiler room is between 78 and 84 degrees.  

I've experimented with using both ducts to push, and with using one to push and one to pull air, in either case I can't get the room above 61 degrees.